# How can I listen to when a template is rendered in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I have some post-processing that I have to do on a list of HTML elements whenever they are updated from the backend. Is there some event (like, onRender) that I can listen to on the template to facilitate this?

Comment: I had a similar problem that I solved using ```observe``` and triggering off of the ```changed``` event. http://docs.meteor.com/#observe

Answer (score 7):

For Meteor starting from 0.4.0 preview, you can use [`Template.myTemplate.rendered`](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered) for this.

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
      console.log('Template has been (re-)rendered');
}
```

Comment: renamed in meteor 1.0.4 to onRendered and now it takes a callback function. see docs http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered

Answer (score 2):

See also this conversation: [Callback after the DOM was updated in Meteor.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109788/callback-after-the-dom-was-updated-in-meteor-js)

I used the technique to set Bootstrap tooltip popup events in the DOM after template (re)rendering in [my CoffeeScript port of the Leaderboard example](https://github.com/srackham/leaderboard-coffeescript).

This in the template:

```
{{enable_tooltips}}
```

Calls this (CoffeeScript) template property method on the client:

```
enable_tooltips: ->
  # Update tooltips after the template has rendered.
  Meteor.defer -> $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip()
  ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Template.userDashboard.onRendered(function() {
  // Initialize animate panel function
  $('.animate-panel').animatePanel();
}
```

renamed in Meteor 1.0.4 from rendered to `onRendered`. Also it now takes a callback function.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered