# How to handle custom jQuery events in Meteor?

Tags: events, meteor

In Metor 0.3.5, when all events were jQuery events, I was able to use use [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and then handle the [`drag` & `dragstop` events](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#events) using a Metor [event map](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps):

```
Template.game.events['dragstop .card'] = function (e) {
    //stuff
};
```

But I just read this in the Meteor mailing list:

> In 0.3.6, event maps no longer depend on jQuery

And sure enough, the above technique no longer seems to work – my `dragstop` handler isn't called at all now.

I'd greatly appreciate any advice as to how to achieve the same effect in 0.3.6.

Comment: I am still on 0.3.5 but have the same issue. No news yet?

Comment: We don't have a story yet for drag-and-drop or interoperation with jQuery UI plug-ins, but we will look into it!  A workaround could be to bind the listener using jQuery instead of an event map.

Comment: @dgreensp Is there any disadvantage to bypassing event maps (aside from having to manually hook up the listeners w/ jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom jQuery events can be bound with plain old jQuery, bypassing [event maps](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps) altogether:

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('dragstop', '.card', function (e) {
        //stuff
    });
});
```

Remember to use jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to bind the handlers, since template elements are not necessarily included in the DOM at all times.

Comment: Don't `.on` works for non-existent DOM elements just when it is bind on `document`? So `$(document).on(events, selector, callback)`? Like `.live` was in previous jQuery API?

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays, you can simply use body events to accomplish this the "Meteor" way:

```
Template.body.events({
    'dragstop #somedivid': function(e) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: And can't get this to work for some reason. Is that still a valid answer?

Comment: Yes, it works as of Meteor 1.2. What issue are you having?