# How can I react to DOM events that Meteor Templates don't support?

Tags: meteor

Currently meteor [supports a limited number of events](http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps) that we can react to from our template definitions. I would like a way to react to events beyond this predefined list. I want the freedom to add any event, even custom events, to the list of possible events in a template.

One idea I had would be to set up a jquery event handler somewhere that listens for the unsupported event and have it set a session variable:

```coffee
$(form).submit( ->
    Session.set('formSubmitted', true)
```

And then use that session variable when rendering a template:

```coffee
Template.confirmation.submitted = ->
    return Session.get('formSubmitted')
```

```xml
<template name="confirmation">
    {{#if submitted}}
        <!-- do whatever -->
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

But this is just a workaround and doesn't really address the issue. Is there a real Meteor-way of doing this? Is this something I can do with the new [Spark](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Spark) implementations?

**NOTE:** Please ignore the fact that I'm using the submit event here. I know I can just bind a click event to the submit button, but that's beside the point.

**NOTE 2:** The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646570/how-to-handle-custom-jquery-events-in-meteor) is also just a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The `rendered` callback is what I use to do this.

http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered

The callback gives you template instance you should use to find the dom elements you need:  http://docs.meteor.com/#template_inst

Untested example below ;)

```cs
Template.foo.rendered = ->
  $(this.find("form")).submit ->
    Session.set 'formSubmitted', true
```

Using a Session variable than to switch the view is a matter of taste I think.

I have an app State stored in the Session, that toggles Templates. Additionally the backbone package is very useful to provide some meaningful urls.

Comment: a problem with that is the event is bound every time the template is rendered, which happens when any of the dependencies change

Comment: I have that problem all the time Dave, do you know any pattern that avoids this?