# Displaying one JS countdown after another

Tags: javascript, meteor, timer

I'm trying to display a second countdown after the first one finishes. I'm using meteor. This is the timer:

```
sec = 5
@timer = setInterval((->
  $('#timer').text sec--
  if sec == -1
    $('#timer').fadeOut 'fast'
    sec=
    timer
  return
), 1000)
```

This is how I call it
When the template is rendered I call a setTimeout and a countdown displays

```
Template.selector.rendered = ->
  window.setTimeout(startGame, 5000)
  timer
```

When game starts I need a second countdown. I managed it like this:

```
sec = 5
sw = 0
@timer = setInterval((->
  $('#timer').text sec--
  if sec == -1
    if sw == 0
      sw = 1
      sec = 20
    else if sw == 1
  clearInterval timer
  return
), 1000)
```

But there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use many timers, you could make an object to achieve that. Here is an example taken from [here](https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-reactive-timer) You could adapt it to your case [using custom events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153205/how-to-trigger-a-custom-event-with-meteor-js):

```
ReactiveTimer = (function () {

    // Constructor
    function ReactiveTimer(interval) {
        this._dependency = new Tracker.Dependency;
        this._intervalId = null;

        if(_.isFinite(interval))
            this.start(interval);

    };

    ReactiveTimer.prototype.start = function(interval){
        var _this = this;

        this._intervalId = Meteor.setInterval(function(){
            // rerun every "interval"
            _this._dependency.changed();
        }, 1000 * interval);
    };

    ReactiveTimer.prototype.stop = function(){
        Meteor.clearInterval(this._intervalId);
        this._intervalId = null;
    };

    ReactiveTimer.prototype.tick = function(){
        this._dependency.depend();
    };

    return ReactiveTimer;
})();
```