# Run JS after rendering a meteor template

Tags: meteor

I have a template that looks something like this:

```
<template name="foo">
  <textarea name="text">{{contents}}</textarea>
</template>
```

I render it with:

```
Template.foo = function() {
  return Foos.find();
}
```

And I have some event handlers:

```
Template.foo.events = {
  'blur textarea': blurHandler
}
```

What I want to do is set the `rows` attribute of the `textarea` depending on the size of its contents. I realize that I could write a Handlebars helper, but it wouldn't have access to the DOM element being rendered, which would force me to do some unnecessary duplication. What I want, ideally, is for meteor to trigger an event after an element is rendered. Something like:

```
Template.foo.events = {
  'render textarea': sizeTextarea
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Callback after the DOM was updated in Meteor.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109788/callback-after-the-dom-was-updated-in-meteor-js)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the current 'best' way to do this (it's a bit of a hack) is to use `Meteor.defer` ala [Callback after the DOM was updated in Meteor.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109788/callback-after-the-dom-was-updated-in-meteor-js).

Geoff is one of the meteor devs, so his word is gospel :)

So in your case, you could do something like:

```
 <textarea id="{{attach_textarea}}">....</textarea>
```

and

```
 Template.foo.attach_textarea = function() {
   if (!this.uuid) this.uuid = Meteor.uuid();

   Meteor.defer(function() {
     $('#' + this.uuid).whatever();
   });

   return this.uuid;
 }
```

**EDIT**

Note, that as 0.4.0, you can do this in a much ad-hoc way (as pointed out by Sander):

```
Template.foo.rendered = function() {
  $(this.find('textarea')).whatever();
}
```

Comment: To make sure I understand - there's nothing magical about having a dynamic id here, just that this function will be called each time the element is rendered?  I.e. you could do this with a data attribute or whatever?

Comment: Hmm, `Meteor.defer` is just a wrapper around `setTimeout(..., 0)`, right? That approach occurred to me, but it could cause visible flicker. I really need a post-render hook that precedes the event loop.

Comment: Having said that, I'm going to accept this answer because my question is a duplicate of the one that you linked to (even though the accepted answer on that one is far from ideal).

Comment: @7zark7: The dynamic id is just there so you can find the relevant element in the Defer call. It's up to you how to do this, using `Meteor.uuid` is just a suggestion.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham: yes, (well Meteor.setTimeout, see docs). So you want something to run after the DOM nodes are attached, but before the nodes are rendered by the browser; i.e. before the rendering thread returns? AFAIK there is no way to hook into that, sorry.

Comment: @7zark7: Oh, I just re-read your comment, you are right, the id will change each time, this is actually a mistake :) Usually I'd attach the uuid to the context (`this`) if it didn't have one already..

Answer (score 21):

As of Meteor 0.4.0 it is possible to check if a template has finished rendering, see http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered

If I understand your question correctly, you should wrap your textarea resize code inside a Template.foo.onRendered function:

```
Template.foo.onRendered(function () {
  this.attach_textarea();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Since about June 2014, the correct way to do this has been to set a callback using  [Template.myTemplate.onRendered()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) .

Comment: It doesn't fire EACH time, only once.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think so - not sure if it's "the right way", but this works for me:

In your app JS, the client section will run whatever javascript there on the client.  For example:

```
if (Meteor.is_client) {
    $(function() {
        $('textarea').attr('rows' , 12) // or whatever you need to do
    })
    ...
```

Note the example here uses JQuery, in which case you need to provide this to the client (I think :-).  In my case:

I created a /client dir, and added jquery.js file under this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that although this might work on the initial draw, it's going to run into issues if the element ever reactively redraws.

Comment: Also, isn't jQuery included with Meteor?  I don't have a jquery.js file anywhere and I haven't added any special jQuery package, but I can use jQuery just fine in my Meteor applications.

Comment: I had to 'meteor add jquery' iirc