# Template load event

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I am using Meteor,so can someone suggest me what could be the event which can be handled after a Template is displayed(not loaded)...?
For example , I have a template which displays a modal popup. Now I want to do something after the template is "displayed" (not loaded). Please suggest me how to handle the respective event.
I have tried,

```
<template name = "SendMessage">

//modal popup code
{{check}}
</template> 

Template.SendMessage.check = function(){
alert("load");
};
```

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109788/callback-after-the-dom-was-updated-in-meteor-js. Is it working for you?

Answer (score 1):

For Meteor starting from 0.4.0 preview, you might want to use [`Template.myTemplate.rendered`](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered) and use a boolean value to track the state within the Template object like this (so it does not get called every time a portion of the template is updated):

```
Template.myTemplate.rendered = function() {
    if(!this._rendered) {
      this._rendered = true;
      alert('load');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive that in this hacky way:

```
Template.SendMessage.check = function(){
   Meteor.defer(function(){ 
         //modal code
   });
};
```

Or more hacky

```
Template.SendMessage.check = function(){
  setTimeout(function(){    
         //modal code
   },0);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have one template which renders once but want to react when the url changes, like load different modals and such.
If that is the case this a possible way.

```
Template.PageDetail.onRendered(function(){
    this.autorun(() => { 
        FlowRouter.watchPathChange();
        // do the thing!
        yourFunction();
    })
})
```