# Why are my <select>'s <option>'s not accessible from a Template.foo.rendered callback?

Tags: meteor

Here's my callback:

```
  Template.joinedRoomsList.rendered = function () {
    // the console.log prints: 'undefined' in client console
    console.log($('#joined-rooms').children().first().html());
    Session.set('currentRoom', $('#joined-rooms').children().first().text());
  }
```

Here's my template:

```
<template name="joinedRoomsList">
  <select id="joined-rooms">
    {{#each joinedRooms}}
      <option>{{name}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>
```

I've tried many different ways to set the Session key 'currentRoom' to the value of the first  in my .

The `console.log` statement prints out `'undefined'`, in the client console, however, when I manually type into the developer console the same thing: `$('#joined-rooms').children().first().html()`, it gives me a value.

Essentially, I'm trying to set the Session key 'currentRoom' to the first  value in the  on page load/body load/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to fix this by calling [defer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109788/callback-after-the-dom-was-updated-in-meteor-js). I guess that you call your methods a bit too early - before the dom had time to render.

```
Template.joinedRoomsList.rendered = function () {
  Meteor.defer(function(){
    console.log($('#joined-rooms').children().first().html());
    Session.set('currentRoom', $('#joined-rooms').children().first().text());
  });
}
```

Comment: Not quite the solution I went with, but close. I ended up using Meteor.setTimeout, can't find Meteor.defer in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try Template's selector, it's more efficient cause we just find elements inside our current Template instead of the whole doom with jQuery.

```
Template.joinedRoomsList.rendered = function() { 
   console.log(this.find("#joined-rooms"));
}
```

Comment: says template is undefined.

Comment: I tried `this.find` and that appears to work, as mentioned here: http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/44771047946/using-meteors-rendered-callback

Comment: The syntax for Meteor 1.1 is ```Template.joinedRoomsList.onRendered(function(){ //calling this here grabs the current template instance})```. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered

Comment: Yeah, that is. (event, template) param is for Templale's events, thank for correct me,  i edited my answer.