# Meteor: How to treat elements that disappear and reappear

Tags: meteor

I have a page, that lists a collection, that can be filtered. 
As there are some fancy effects (hover dimming) on these items, they have to be applied once the page has loaded.

This works fine, but when I select a criteria that hides an item, and then make it reappear by deleting that filter, these effects are no longer applied to these items.

I have tried to create a `template.rendered` function, but that only works on the first page load.

I also thought that adding a `'hover #mydiv: function () {...}'` inside the `template.events` section could help, but that still doesn't work.

I have even tried to listen to the changes made in the drop-down (`'change #myselect': function () {...}`) where the filters can be applied, but that's not working either.

I also tried to tie it to a dependency, that is submitted when the criteria is selected, that has also failed.

Any suggestions what else should I try?

Thanks,
Alex

**Edit 1:**

This is how I treat the filters:

in `Template.search.events`:

```
'change #search-skills-select': function () {
    Session.set('searchFilter', $('#search-skills-select').val());
}
```

This then goes to:

```
/* This is of course properly handled for nulls, undefineds, etc. */
var searchFilterString = Session.get('searchFilter');

Profiles.find({profileAttributes: {
                    $all: searchFilterString
                 }
             });
```

Comment: could you show the code you are using to "filter" the items ?

Comment: @Guillaume Yes, I've pasted it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this on your child template (the one that appears and disappears):

```
<template name="mytemplate">
  <div id="my-magic-div">
    .. stuff goes here ..
    {{add_my_special_behavior}}
  </div>
</template>
```

and then add code:

```
Template.mytemplate.add_my_special_behavior = function () {
  Meteor.defer(function () {
    // in here, `this` means the template context
  });
};
```

(inspired on https://stackoverflow.com/a/10119993/5109168)

Comment: May your name be praised by the Heavens! Thanks, this did the trick!

Comment: "...haaaaaaalelujah!"